# How to make dotnet publish command use private Nuget sources

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I am using VS2019 (16.4) within a company walls. I changed the VS Nuget sources and my solution compiles and runs after several requests to our internal foundation to approve Nuget packages.

Now I am trying to use the `dotnet publish` command, but it fails miserably with bunch of errors such as: `error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.`.

I figured it is probably not cognizant of the private Nuget sources.....so I searched around and the solution seems to be to include a `NuGet.Config` file at the solution root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Company Artifactory" value="https://repo.comany.com/artifactory/api/nuget/comany-nuget" />
    <add key="Company Eval Artifactory" value="https://repo.comany.com/artifactory/api/nuget/comany-nuget-eval" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This did not help.   It seems that there is a new `dotnet` command that will allow adding sources via the CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source but unfortunately our version is is `3.1.100` and the new command is applicable to `3.1.200`...yes...it will take an act congress to get the new version in our company.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is also a global nuget config, you can add package sources to it as well. Also, IIRC, Artifactory requires custom access token, you should manage it as well

Comment: You can do pretty much everything done by `dotnet nuget` command manually by directly modifying the `nuget.config` file. `dotnet nuget` doesn't really do anything else behind the scenes (other than uploading/deleting packages to nuget.org).

Comment: Thank you! @omajid Actually `dotnet nuget` is another thing I am not understanding properly. It looks like it has only 3 commands: `delete`, `locals` and `push`. None of these help me provide Nuget sources ....am I mistaken here?

Comment: Like I said in my post, we have version 3.1.100 which does not support the newly added command `add`.

Comment: What I mean is: 3.1.200 has new `dotnet nuget` commands, but, to the best of my knowledge, they just modify the `nuget.config` file. You can modify the `nuget.config` file by hand, without relying on the new `dotnet nuget` commands. If you want to add a new source, instead of `dotnet nuget add source..` you can just add a `<add>` element with the source in your `nuget.config` file by hand.

Comment: @omajid Ok...yes....but I added a `NuGet.Config` file (it seems like it is case sensitive) and I can see that VS recognizes the newly added sources...but not when I run from the command line. Is there a way to know what the currently configured Nuget sources from the dotne tCLI?

Comment: `dotnet restore -v:n` will show you the `nuget.config` files being used as well as any additional feeds (aside from nuget.org) being used.

Comment: @omajid ok...I apologize....the `NyGet.Config` seems to be picked up. I found out, however, that the real problem is the `-r win-x64` switch in my publish command: `otnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release -o c:\work\some-dest /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:DebugType=None`

Comment: If I add it, it causes all the problems....if I remove it, it says that `publish an application to a single-file without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier`!!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @omajid for your help. Here is what works for me:

In each project root folder:

- `dotnet restore`
- `dotnet build --configuration Release`
- `dotnet publish --no-restore -r win-x64 -c Release -o c:\somwhere /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:DebugType=None`

The above requires that we add the runtime identifier to the project file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.2.0</AssemblyVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Unfortunately, restore with runtime identifier did not work (same errors as in my original problem) which would probably mean that a runtime identifier is not needed in the project file:
`dotnet restore --runtime win-x64`

My initial observation was incorrect! Nuget sources were NOT causing the restore problems in `publish`....it was the runtime identifier. I still do not know why the error was manifested the way it did ...but calling `dotnet publish` with `--no-restore` switch seems to have done it for me.

The problem remains as to why `dotnet restore --runtime win-x64` fails.

Comment: By [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish), the `build` command does also the _restore_, so in this case, you will need to invoke the build with `--no-restore` as well. Also, the `publish` command does also _build_ and _restore_.